# Standard hydrogen electrode, why hydrogen?

Tags: electrochemistry

Why is the hydrogen electrode used as the reference to set electrode potentials? Could any other element be used instead?

Comment: That's simply for convenience. Any other reference point would do just as well. But we live in a world full of hydrogen (in the form of water), so this is our primary interest.

Comment: It's worth noting that I've been told (by a couple of battery researchers) that the [silver chloride electrode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_chloride_electrode) is the de-facto reference in most labs. It comes in a convenient package which doesn't require you to bubble a gas at 1 bar over a catalyst in a 1M acid (all of which would have to be re-calibrated every time you ran an experiment)

Answer (score 3):

There are two separate issues here. The first one is defining a zero for potential. In theoretical physics, it is the energy of two charges separated by infinity distance.

In electrochemistry, this is *chosen* to be the potential of the hydrogen electrode since that is something that can be made reproducibly and hydrogen was the de facto 'zero' for a number of other quantities.

These days, there are much more practical and easy to use reference electrodes like the silver/silver chloride (as chipbuster mentioned) or the saturated calomel or the mercury/mercurous sulfate. Here is a good list of them from a manufacturer of such electrodes: http://www.koslow.com/select_reference_probe

Full disclosure: I used to work for a company that resells electrodes from Koslow.

Answer (score 1):

There are different approaching points here. One is history: The hydrogen electrode has been used forever and people are used to defining values relative to it, so why not continue?

A second point of approach is the following: You cannot measure *absolute* potentials; you *need* some kind of a reference. The choice was completely arbitrary. However, there are some ‘rationalisations’ (that probably only turned up after hydrogen was already used):

- Hydrogen is the first element in the periodic system. It is nice to have ‘number one’ as your reference.
- The potential of hydrogen (hydrogen gas at 1 bar in an acidic solution of pH 0) is approximately equivalent to that encountered in 1 molar acidic solutions (sulphuric, hydrochloric, nitric acid etc.). Probably even predating the selection of hydrogen, metals that dissolved in 1 molar acid were termed *non-noble* and those that resisted the acid were *noble*. Using the hydrogen potential as a zero-point, the non-noble metals have a negative standard potential while noble ones have a positive. An easy way to distinguish noble metals just by a number.

But just to restate: *The choice of the electrode as a standard was likely before the second implication was fully realised*.